# d3 how to add image to the label of a graph node?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've made a fast stand-alone part of the project I have as to show you my problem. I have this circle that represent a node in my graph and what I want is to have on mouseover a box appearing with some text and image. This far I have the node, the box and the text. My problem is that the image doesn't appear, there is only a border of the space dedicated to the image and nothing inside.
I don't know if I'am using the right order of appending things?
I`m using a div that is created initially and it's invisible, then I create the circle and bind a listener to it for the mouseover event. The listener appends to the div a text field and the image. For the image it gives the href attribute and on mouseout it renders the div invisible again. Would you help me find what is going wrong in all this....thank you!

```
    //the box, invisible for now
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "10")
    .style("width","60px")                  
    .style("height","28px")                 
    .style("padding","2px")             
    .style("font","12px sans-serif")
    .style("border","0px")      
    .style("border-radius","8px")  
    .style("background", "lightsteelblue")
.style("visibility", "hidden");

    //the svg container
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);

    //the node        
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "logo")
        .attr("cx", 225)
        .attr("cy", 225)
        .attr("r", 20)
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            tooltip.text("some text"); 
            tooltip.append("image")
                    .attr("href","https://github.com/favicon.ico")
                    .attr("x", -8)
                    .attr("y", -8)
                    .attr("width","16px")                  
                    .attr("height","12px"); 
            tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-                   
                                      10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

Comment: You probably want to append an `img` instead of an `image`.

Comment: it doesn`t matter from what i see, because img and image have the same effect on the page. They both create an <image> tag with the right attributes.

Comment: I mean replace `tooltip.append("image")` with `tooltip.append("img")`.

Comment: What I ment was that I did as you say, but nothing changed. I think that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, you also need to change `href` to `src` -- http://jsfiddle.net/E67cy/ Will add an answer.

Comment: Lars, the "src" thing did the job!!! Thank you, how did you knew? I mean it is stragne because HTML uses href, d3 uses xlink:href ...so?

Comment: This is just normal HTML -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `image` to `img` and `href` to `src`. Complete working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E67cy/).

Comment: It works just fine. There is one other thing that still bothers me. If you comment the line " //tooltip.text("some text");" you`ll see that it appends a new img for every mouseover event and i`m not sure why? My guess is  that when there is the text d3 appends the image at the exact same place everytime, which is just "-8" from the text.  Is that right, and if it is, is that normal?

Comment: When you use `.text()`, you're overwriting everything contained within the element, including any appended elements. You could modify the code to have separate `div` and `img` elements in the tooltip and then modify only the `div` for the text.